# Can I get an identifier for a stored fingerprint?

Tags: android-biometric

I want to increase the level of security of my android device with implementing an auth method that requires a series of fingerprints in a specific order.
For example: pointer finer, middle finger, little finger
To make this work I would need to be able to get a unique identifier for a successfully verified fprint.

So if I would receive the result that the finger was successfully matched with fprintX I could implement such a feature.

Does that work with the biometric auth api today?

Comment: On successful authentication, BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult is passed to the onAuthenticationSucceeded callback. 
You can get authentication type and associated crypto object. But it seems there is no API to know which fingerprint matched.

Comment: I guess, you have to manually take care results of all fingers and their orders as well.